How can i have a progress indicator and video buffer rate that remains within the boundaries of each video chapters like Youtube does?
I am making a custom video player.
this video may contain chapters, so i map through these chapters and make a div for each one with a gap between them like youtube does.
problem is the progress rate indicator and the buffer rate indicator overlaps with the chapters and covers the gap.
Here is picture of what i made:
Supposedly there was a gap for the chapter where I marked, but the progress indicator rate covered that gap.
this is what I want the progress bar to be like:
As you can see the progress rate didn't cover the chapters gap
Here is the code: https://github.com/mohammadmansour200/my-react-app

Could you give an example of the variable values that demonstrate the behavior please?

@wongjn Here is full example: https://github.com/mohammadmansour200/my-react-app

the code snippet in the answer was in a very big component so here is a more simple one

You could consider having two copies of the chapter elements, on top of each other. Use clip-path() to "trim" the progress bar to the correct width.
To do this, first replace the progress element with a copy of the chapter elements, but colored the same black. Here, I've kept it DRY by refactoring the chapter elements to a new component:
function Chapters({ color }) {
  return (
    <div className="absolute flex w-full -translate-y-[3px] flex-row-reverse gap-1">
      {APIData.chapter.map((chapter) => {
        const chapterWidth = `${
          (unformatTimestamp(chapter.chapterStart) /
            unformatTimestamp(APIData.duration)) *
          100
        }%`;

        return (
          <div
            key={chapter.chapterStart}
            style={{
              width: chapterWidth,
            }}
            className={`h-[6px] ${color} ${
              chapterWidth === "0%" ? "flex-grow" : ""
            }`}
          ></div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

{/* Video chapters */}
<Chapters color="bg-black/50" />
{/* Video progress rate */}
<Chapters color="bg-black" />



const { useState, useRef } = React;

const APIData = {
  duration: "5:00",
  chapter: [
    {
      chapterTitle: "test",
      chapterStart: "0:00",
    },
    {
      chapterTitle: "test 2",
      chapterStart: "3:34",
    },
  ],
};

function unformatTimestamp(duration) {
  const splittedDuration = duration.split(":");

  const hours = splittedDuration.length === 2 ? undefined : splittedDuration[0];
  const minutes =
    hours === undefined ? splittedDuration[0] : splittedDuration[1];
  const seconds =
    hours === undefined ? splittedDuration[1] : splittedDuration[2];

  if (hours === undefined && minutes === "0") {
    return parseInt(seconds);
  } else if (minutes !== undefined && hours === undefined) {
    const calcSeconds = parseInt(minutes) * 60 + parseInt(seconds);
    return calcSeconds;
  } else if (hours !== undefined) {
    const calcSeconds =
      parseInt(hours) * 3600 + parseInt(minutes) * 60 + parseInt(seconds);
    return calcSeconds;
  }
}

function Chapters({ color }) {
  return (
    <div className="absolute flex w-full -translate-y-[3px] flex-row-reverse gap-1">
      {APIData.chapter.map((chapter) => {
        const chapterWidth = `${
          (unformatTimestamp(chapter.chapterStart) /
            unformatTimestamp(APIData.duration)) *
          100
        }%`;

        return (
          <div
            key={chapter.chapterStart}
            style={{
              width: chapterWidth,
            }}
            className={`h-[6px] ${color} ${
              chapterWidth === "0%" ? "flex-grow" : ""
            }`}
          ></div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const sliderElRef = useRef(null);
  function onSliderInput() {
    setProgress(sliderElRef.current.value);
  }
  console.log(progress);

  return (
    <div className="flex w-full items-center gap-2 text-xs font-semibold opacity-85">
      0:00
      <div className="relative flex w-full items-center">
        {/* Video slider */}
        <input
          ref={sliderElRef}
          onInput={onSliderInput}
          max="100"
          min="0"
          step="0.01"
          type="range"
          defaultValue="0"
          className="progress-bar absolute z-[4] h-[6px]  w-full cursor-pointer select-none appearance-none rounded-2xl bg-transparent"
        />
        <div className="relative w-full">
          {APIData.chapter.length !== 0 && APIData.chapter !== undefined && (
            <React.Fragment>
              {/* Video chapters */}
              <Chapters color="bg-black/50" />
              {/* Video progress rate */}
              <Chapters color="bg-black" />
            </React.Fragment>
          )}

          {/* Video buffer rate */}
          <div className="absolute w-full -translate-y-[3px]">
            <div
              style={{ width: "10%" }}
              className="h-[6px] rounded-full bg-black/40"
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      5:00
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<div id="root"></div>



Then, apply clip-path: inset() to the progress element, clipping from the right edge only, using the invert of the progress variable value:
function Chapters({ color, style = {} }) {
  return (
    <div … style={style}>

{/* Video progress rate */}
<Chapters … style={{ clipPath: `inset(0 ${100 - progress}% 0 0)` }} />



const { useState, useRef } = React;

const APIData = {
  duration: "5:00",
  chapter: [
    {
      chapterTitle: "test",
      chapterStart: "0:00",
    },
    {
      chapterTitle: "test 2",
      chapterStart: "3:34",
    },
  ],
};

function unformatTimestamp(duration) {
  const splittedDuration = duration.split(":");

  const hours = splittedDuration.length === 2 ? undefined : splittedDuration[0];
  const minutes =
    hours === undefined ? splittedDuration[0] : splittedDuration[1];
  const seconds =
    hours === undefined ? splittedDuration[1] : splittedDuration[2];

  if (hours === undefined && minutes === "0") {
    return parseInt(seconds);
  } else if (minutes !== undefined && hours === undefined) {
    const calcSeconds = parseInt(minutes) * 60 + parseInt(seconds);
    return calcSeconds;
  } else if (hours !== undefined) {
    const calcSeconds =
      parseInt(hours) * 3600 + parseInt(minutes) * 60 + parseInt(seconds);
    return calcSeconds;
  }
}

function Chapters({ color, style = {} }) {
  return (
    <div className="absolute flex w-full -translate-y-[3px] flex-row-reverse gap-1" style={style}>
      {APIData.chapter.map((chapter) => {
        const chapterWidth = `${
          (unformatTimestamp(chapter.chapterStart) /
            unformatTimestamp(APIData.duration)) *
          100
        }%`;

        return (
          <div
            key={chapter.chapterStart}
            style={{
              width: chapterWidth,
            }}
            className={`h-[6px] ${color} ${
              chapterWidth === "0%" ? "flex-grow" : ""
            }`}
          ></div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const sliderElRef = useRef(null);
  function onSliderInput() {
    setProgress(sliderElRef.current.value);
  }
  console.log(progress);

  return (
    <div className="flex w-full items-center gap-2 text-xs font-semibold opacity-85">
      0:00
      <div className="relative flex w-full items-center">
        {/* Video slider */}
        <input
          ref={sliderElRef}
          onInput={onSliderInput}
          max="100"
          min="0"
          step="0.01"
          type="range"
          defaultValue="0"
          className="progress-bar absolute z-[4] h-[6px]  w-full cursor-pointer select-none appearance-none rounded-2xl bg-transparent"
        />
        <div className="relative w-full">
          {APIData.chapter.length !== 0 && APIData.chapter !== undefined && (
            <React.Fragment>
              {/* Video chapters */}
              <Chapters color="bg-black/50" />
              {/* Video progress rate */}
              <Chapters color="bg-black" style={{ clipPath: `inset(0 ${100 - progress}% 0 0)` }} />
            </React.Fragment>
          )}

          {/* Video buffer rate */}
          <div className="absolute w-full -translate-y-[3px]">
            <div
              style={{ width: "10%" }}
              className="h-[6px] rounded-full bg-black/40"
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      5:00
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<div id="root"></div>



